# jenkins calling batch file get stuck in windows 7

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, jenkins, cmd

I have a Jenkins server in windows 7 environment, and I run a batch file from jenkins. This batch file launches a jar that calls `cmd.exe` in order to connect to an instrument (spirent).

The above batch file fails when is started from jenkins, installed as a windows service, but works fine either if is started directly from cmd or from a jenkins started as

```
java -jar jenkins.war.....
```

Comment: Is the windows service user running jenkins different than the user you are logged in as?  If so, could be a permissions issue.

Comment: I have run into enough issues running Jenkins as a service on windows that I actually have an auto login process that then launch my Jenkins windows slave automatically upon login, just leaving the user up.  Certainly not best practice, I'm sure, but it works for me.

Comment: Hi Evan, yes the windows jenkins service is different than the user is logged on.

Comment: Hi,the problem is solved , now the jenkins windows server is running withe the same user that is logged on

Comment: Going to add my comments as the answer, then.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the windows service user running Jenkins is different than the user you are logged in as, you are likely running into a permissions issue. Possible solutions include changing the user running the service or modifying permissions necessary to allow the service user to perform the desired tasks.